# Scp command says Connection Timed out in Centos 7

Tags: centos7, scp

I am trying to send a file from a remote server to my local machine. I am using the following command:

`scp username@my-env-13.net:/root/myFile.txt C:\Users\Folder`

This command does not send anything, and it shows a message saying "Connection timed out". I also don't have any idea what port should be used. My remote server is using port 32110.

SHowever, sending files from my local machine to the remote server works fine, I have used:

`scp -P 32110 newFile.txt  username@my-env-13.net:/root`

What am I doing wrong?